# How do i get the supported typefaces for a given font family in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a font family popup button which lets the user select a font. I also have corresponding font face popup button and a font size combo button in my UI. When a user changes the font family, I want to update the font face popup button's menu with the supported faces/traits for that font family. Could someone please let me know how this is done.

TextEdit seems to do it and I could not figure out how. I have attached a screenshot of the textedit toolbar font popups. I want to mimic these controls in my app.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableMembersOfFontFamily:]` to get an array of font descriptions (not instances of `NSFont`) in the specified font family. If you have a font already and want its font family, use `-[NSFont fontFamily]`.

For the specific format of the returned array, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFontManager/availableMembersOfFontFamily%3a) for `NSFontManager`.